# C sockets: recv(...) not returning correct bytes

Tags: c, http, sockets

If I telnet into `telnet www.xlhi.com 80`, and apply the following GET request:

```
GET http://www.xlhi.com/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.xlhi.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: CG=IE:04:Cork
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

I get the following response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 06 Dec 2011 10:35:08 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.9
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 48
Content-Type: text/html

��(�ͱ���I�O����H�����ч��
                          �4�@�
```

Everything is fine and as expected. I'm interested in the gzipped binary data returned ("Hello").

Now, I have this C function which applies a GET request to a server (in this case www.xlhi.com)

```
char* applyGetReq(char* url,char* data,int len){
        int sockfd, numbytes;
        struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
        int rv;
        char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

        memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
        hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
        printf("Server name: %s\n\n",url);
        if ((rv = getaddrinfo(url,"80", &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
                exit(1);
        }

        // loop through all the results and connect to the first we can
        for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
                if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
                        perror("client: socket");
                        continue;
                }
                if (connect(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
                        close(sockfd);
                        perror("client: connect");
                        continue;
                }
                break;
        }

        if (p == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "client: failed to connect\n");
                exit(1);
        }

        inet_ntop(p->ai_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)p->ai_addr),s, sizeof s);
        //printf("client: connecting to %s\n", s);

        sendall(sockfd,data,&len);

        freeaddrinfo(servinfo); // all done with this structure

        char* buf=malloc(MAXDATASIZE*sizeof(char));
        if ((numbytes = recv(sockfd, buf, MAXDATASIZE-1, 0)) == -1) {
                perror("recv");
                exit(1);
        }
        //printf("numbytes:%d\n",numbytes);
        buf[numbytes] = '\0';
        close(sockfd);
        return buf;
}
```

Now, when I call this function and print out the result:

```
    ...
    int len = strlen(data);   //data is a char[] and contains the exact same GET request as mentioned above
    char* buf=NULL;
    buf=applyGetReq(stripped_url,data,len);
    printf("%s\n",buf);
```

I get the following response from the server:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 06 Dec 2011 10:03:13 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.9
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 48
Content-Type: text/html

�
```

As you can see, the page contents (binary data) is cut short for some unexplained reason. I should be getting:

```
��(�ͱ���I�O����H�����ч��
                              �4�@�
```

I've been looking at this for two hours now and can't seem to get to the bottom of it so I thought I'd ask the community.

Comment: Not all characters in your binary data are printable, maybe this is the reason why you get different outputs. did you try to print the binary data in hex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's how `printf` works. It stops when it encounters a NUL (0) byte. Try to use another function

```
fwrite(buf, 1, numbytes, stdout);
```

Comment: @Eamorr I added an example with `fwrite`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that. I can see the binary data now. I now have to extract the length of the response from the response header. Phew! I thought my code was a lot worse than it is.